# Getting best allrounder

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of players. They are categories into three which are as follows.

```
Name    Position    Batting Average

Sourav  Allrounder  40.73

Yuvraj  Allrounder  36.56

Irfan   Allrounder  23.39

Laxman  Batsman         30.76

Rahul   Batsman         39.17

Virender Batsman    35.06

Sachin   Batsman    44.83

Zaheer    Bowler    12

Anil      Bowler    10.54

Harbhajan Bowler    13.3
```

I would like to choose the best allrounder based on batting average. Same will go with the batsman and the bowler.

I am not able to loop it through to get the result.

Regards,

The expected result would be like :

```
Sourav  Allrounder  40.73

Rahul   Batsman         39.17

Harbhajan Bowler    13.3
```

Comment: For a formula solution [Chip Pearsons](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/rank.aspx) sit may offer some pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:
I assumed first row is the title row and that the column indexes are as follows:
Name : "A"
Position : "B"
Score : "C"
I also assumed that the players are listed with no empty rows and that at the end of the row there were no unrelated entries.

```
Sub stackOverflow()
    Dim playerCount As Integer, playerIndex As Integer
    Dim highestAllrounder As String, highestBatsman As String, highestBowler As String
    Dim maxAllrounder As Double, maxBatsman As Double, maxBowler As Double
    Dim player As String, position As String, score As Double
    maxAllrounder = 0
    maxBatsman = 0
    maxBowler = 0
    playerCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'finds the last row with entry in column "A"
    For playerIndex = 1 To (playerCount - 1)
        player = Cells((playerIndex + 1), 1).Value   '+1 for title row
        position = Cells((playerIndex + 1), 2).Value
        score = Cells((playerIndex + 1), 3).Value
        If position = "Allrounder" And score > maxAllrounder Then
            highestAllrounder = player
            maxAllrounder = score
        ElseIf position = "Batsman" And score > maxBatsman Then
            highestBatsman = player
            maxBatsman = score
        ElseIf position = "Bowler" And score > maxBowler Then
            highestBowler = player
            maxBowler = score
        End If
    Next playerIndex
    MsgBox "AllRounder: " & highestAllrounder & " - " & maxAllrounder & vbNewLine & "Batsman: " & highestBatsman & " - " & maxBatsman & vbNewLine & "Bowler: " & highestBowler & " - " & maxBowler
End Sub
```

Turns out your expected results are wrong. You could achieve the same result by using collections, but I tried to keep it at the beginner level.